# Verify: If $0<\alpha<1$, $0\leq \beta$, then there exists $M(\alpha,\beta)>0$ so that $z^\beta e^{-z}\leq Me^{-\alpha z}$ for all $z\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Verify: If $0<\alpha<1$, $0\leq \beta$, then there exists
    $M(\alpha,\beta)>0$ so that  $$z^\beta e^{-z}\leq Me^{-\alpha z}$$
    for all $z\geq 0$

**For part (1)**, I noticed that the left hand side of the inequality is equivalent to a gamma function. So,
$$\int_0^\infty z^\beta e^{-z}\,dz=\beta !.$$ If I integrate the right hand side of the inequality I get 
$$\int_0^\infty M e^{-az}\,dz=M.$$ 
So if I choose $M(\alpha,\beta)\geq \beta!$. I have proven the inequality?

**Is this correct?**

**EDIT:** Proof: Let $f(z)=z^\beta e^{-(1-\alpha)z}$, with $0<\alpha<1$, $0\leq \beta$. Then 
$$f'(z) 
= \beta z^{\beta -1}e^{-(1-\alpha)z}+z^\beta e^{-(1-\alpha)z}(\alpha-1)
= z^{\beta -1}e^{-(1-\alpha)z}[\beta +z(\alpha-1)]
$$
Recall the first derivative test, which states:

*"If $f'(x)>0$ on an open interval extending left from $x_0$ and $f'(x)<0$ on an open interval extending right from $x_0$, then $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $x_0$.*

Note that $z^{\beta -1}\geq 0$ (since $z\geq 0$), $e^{-(1-\alpha)z}\geq 0$. So $f'(z)=0$ at
$z=0$ and $z=-\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha-1}=\dfrac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$, with $z\geq 0$. When $z=0$ we can't test the open interval extending to the left, which doesn't give us any useful information.

When $z=\dfrac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$,  choose $z_{-}=\dfrac{\beta-1}{1-\alpha}$ and $z_+=\dfrac{\beta +1}{1-\alpha}$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f'(z_{-}) & = \left(\dfrac{\beta-1}{1-\alpha}\right)^{\beta -1}\exp\left[-(1-\alpha)\dfrac{\beta-1}{1-\alpha}\right]\cdot \left[\beta +\dfrac{\beta-1}{1-\alpha}(\alpha-1)\right] \\
& = \left(\dfrac{\beta-1}{1-\alpha}\right)^{\beta -1}\exp\left[-(\beta-1) \right]\cdot 1 \\
f'(z_{+}) & = \left(\dfrac{\beta+1}{1-\alpha}\right)^{\beta -1}\exp\left[-(1-\alpha)\dfrac{\beta+1}{1-\alpha}\right]\cdot \left[\beta +\dfrac{\beta+1}{1-\alpha}(\alpha-1)\right] \\
& = \left(\dfrac{\beta+1}{1-\alpha}\right)^{\beta -1}\exp\left[-(\beta+1) \right]\cdot -1 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

**However, it isn't obvious which is positive or negative. Help?**

Comment: As far as (a) goes that is about as far from a correct proof as you can get.

Go back to basics and apply the first derivative test to $f(z) = z^\beta e^{(\alpha - 1)z}$.

Worry about parts (b) and (c) later.

Comment: I don't think it is helpful to say what you did about "As far as (a) goes that is about as far from a correct proof as you can get. Go back to basics..,". I find it very rude. But thank you for the hint.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I hope you understand your argument isn't fixable. You can report abusive posts with flags for moderator attention if you feel offended.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I implemented your hint. So you can see the edits

Comment: You are really close. Define $z_0 = \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$. You have $f'(z) > 0$ if $0 < z < z_0$ and $f'(z) < 0$ if $z > z_0$. What does this tell you?

Comment: Then there is a local maximum at $z_0$. So, then I set $M=f(z_0)$. Right?

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: Perfect. Now that part (1) is completed. Is my approach for parts (2) and (3) the correct thinking?

Comment: You will need to carry out the calculations, but yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: I edited my post with what I have done for part (b). What is the derivative of $|x|^2$ with respect to $x_i$?

Comment: Please allow me to suggest a much much simpler proof : by L'Hopitals rule we see easily that $\frac {e^{z}} {z^{n}} \to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$ for any non-negative integer n. Now $\frac {e^{(1-\alpha)z}} {z^{\beta}}$ $ \leq $\frac {e^{z}} {z^{n}}$ if $n > \beta$ and $z \geq 1$. From this we get $e^{-z} \geq e^{-z} z^{-\beta} m$ for some $m>0$. It is now easy to complete the proof.